# Is there any existing automation tools to deploy Kubernetes HA cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

The question is same as the title. I am deploying Kubernetes Cluster on CentOS 7  using Kubeadm and planning to replicate the Master with HA solution.

Although there are loads of tools listed in the [Kubernetes wiki page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#bare-metal), "Building a High-Available" cluster" is a separate topic and there is no automation tools recommended by K8s yet.

The question is whether there is a tool to automated the HA setup steps. What is the most efficient tool to do that ? Will Kubeadm support HA in future and when will it?

Answer (score 1):

A ton of them, and a search before posting would have easily surfaced that very answer

https://github.com/ramitsurana/awesome-kubernetes#readme

Comment: Thanks for answering. The summary is great! I did do a search [here]https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#bare-metal  before asking but ended up finding nothing useful. From the installers listed in the link, kops and kube-aws supports HA deployment for AWS for the time being. Kubespray does not support latest k8s version.  Bookube does not HA deployment. etc. Would you kindly tell me what the most mature tool to install HA cluster on bare-metal till now from you expertise?

Comment: Hi ichbinblau, i'm currently sailing in the same boat and proceeding HA installation manually. Let me know if you found out any automated solution.Thx

Comment: @matthew I went on to that awesome-kubernetes page but there is tons of stuff there, a page search for "High" did not show anything useful. Can you point to something specific?

Comment: [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/releases/tag/v2.5.0) ships with [HA](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/v2.5.0/docs/ha-mode.md). Arguably it would be harder to find a cluster provisioning tool that is _not_ HA nowadays.